# Why can't maple solve the integral $\int x^2 \sqrt{R^2-x^2} dx$?

Tags: maple

I ran into this integral in a problem in which I was trying to [calculate moment of inertia](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286328/how-to-calculate-the-moment-of-inertia-of-a-uniform-disk-about-an-axis-passing-t/4286363#4286363).

I used Maple to try to solve it but Maple just returns the integral itself. I do not know why it can't do the trigonometric substitution and solve the integral.

```
int(x^2*sqrt(R^2 - x^2), x = 0 .. R)
```

Comment: Does the unspecified version of Maple you are using evaluate `int(x^2*sqrt(R^2 - x^2), x)`?

Comment: @EricTowers I am using Maple 2021, and yes the integral you asked about does get solved. That is the original integral without the integration limits. Why is this.

Comment: The following is 100% a guess: the expression `x` or `R` also evaluates in your Maple session and this prior definition of that name is causing problems here.  It's a guess, I could be wrong.  Just evaluating `x` and then `R` will determine if this guess is correct.

Answer (score 6):

You asked "why" it happens. It happens because the answer depends on the whether `R` is greater or less then `0`, and you have not told Maple what to do about that. In the syntax of Maple's `int` command the range `0..R` does not by itself imply that `R` is greater than `0`. That syntax also allows for inverted ranges.

When I execute your original call I get the following warning *in addition to* the unevaluated result.

```
int(x^2*sqrt(R^2-x^2),x=0..R);

Warning, unable to determine if -R is
between 0 and R; try to use assumptions
or use the AllSolutions option
```

Warnings are usually emitted for a good reason, and it is a good idea to learn to try and read them. Suitably following either of its two suggestions can obtain an answer.

The following answer contains a piecewise.

```
int(x^2*sqrt(R^2-x^2),x=0..R,allsolutions);

         4    /{ -1        R <= 0\
   1/16 R  Pi |{                 |
              \{ 1         0 < R /
```

Using assumptions we could separately attain either of those two conditional results.

```
int(x^2*sqrt(R^2-x^2),x=0..R) assuming R>0;

             4
            R  Pi
            -----
             16

int(x^2*sqrt(R^2-x^2),x=0..R) assuming R<0;

             4
            R  Pi
          - -----
             16
```

Another good idea is reading the Help page for the [int](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=int) command, and its related page for Help topic [int,details](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=int/details). These are avaliable offline, in the product's own Help system. It contains examples of the functionality I used here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I get.  Maple 2019.2

[image]

Did you get that warning?  If not, perhaps you turned it off in one of your preferences.